# How to add credentials for sbt-launcher to access custom repository for bootstrap

Tags: sbt

I'm overriding repository in sbt.boot.properties file so that the bootstrap loads the file from company repository. Here is fragment in that file:

```
[repositories]
  local
  typesafe-ivy-releases:  https://artifactory.mycompay.com/artifactory/simple/typesafe2-ivy/, [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext], bootOnly
```

How should I provide credentials for that boot time load?

Answer (score 1):

Add environment variable SBT_CREDENTIALS that contains path to file with credentials.
It was $HOME/.ivy2/.credentials in my case.
Then I could see

> credentials added: Artifactory Realm@mycompany.jfrog.io joedoe/***************

in ~/.sbt/boot/update.log file.

Comment: Thanks, setting `SBT_CREDENTIALS` was the missing piece in my case!